# django - view for redirecting to another page with query recieved

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-views

I have two search inputs, first on home page another on search results itself. what i m try to do is receive query form home and redirect it to search results page according to this :
Like I search - html-5
redirect page should be  - 127.0.0.1/html-5/find/?q=html-5
I have tried but unfortunately not getting the right way to it, please suggest me the correct way to do it. 
I use these url patterns

```
url(r'^(?P<key>.*)/find/', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),
url(r'^search/',category_query_view,name='category_query'),
```

then in category_query

```
def category_query_view(request):
category = request.GET.get('q')
print('hihi',category)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('haystack_search', kwargs={'key':category},))
```

It is redirecting me to

```
127.0.0.1/html-5/find/
```

but i don't know how to add

```
/?q=html-5
```

in after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I get the right way, its pretty simple

```
def category_query_view(request):
category = request.GET.get('q')
print('hihi',category)
url = '{category}/find/?q={category}'.format(category=category)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/'+url)
```